# how can set homepage by routing angular2

Tags: angular, routes

in Angular2 in routing part my code is this,but why the homepage(default page) is not what I have set?
app.module.ts:

```
import {RouterModule}   from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'addProperty',
    component: AddPropertyComponent
  },
 {
   path: 'list-property',
   component: ListPropertyComponent
 },
  {
    path: 'search-place-auto',
    component: SearchPlaceAuto
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
 {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'home',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 }
]),
]
})
```

and app.component.ts:

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
 import {AddPropertyComponent} from './componentes/add-property.component';


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `      
  <header-component></header-component>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <login></login>
  <footer></footer>
      `
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

I think it is simple or maybe I have made mistake.
Thanks a lot

Comment: The snippets you provided seem to work. Can you post more code or even better a plunker? Does the console (developer tools in browser) show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Add **/** to redirectTo: 'home' so it will be `redirectTo: '/home'`; the position doesn't matter and [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hQ8Ke8lNgr2XgCd8Qffr?p=preview) that will automatically redirect to roles page all routes in app.routing.module

```
    import {RouterModule}   from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'addProperty',
    component: AddPropertyComponent
  },
 {
   path: 'list-property',
   component: ListPropertyComponent
 },
  {
    path: 'search-place-auto',
    component: SearchPlaceAuto
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
 {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: '/home',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 }
]),
]
})
```

Comment: thank you but I think the problem is somewhere else because it hasn't fixed yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to give home as default first, Replace following code snippet in your rout config.

```
import {RouterModule}   from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'addProperty',
    component: AddPropertyComponent
  },
 {
   path: 'list-property',
   component: ListPropertyComponent
 },
  {
    path: 'search-place-auto',
    component: SearchPlaceAuto
  },
   { 
    path: '',
   redirectTo: '/home',
   pathMatch: 'full'
   },

  {
   path: 'home',
   component: HomeComponent
  },
]),
]
})
```